# How can I add meta noindex to all catalog search result pages in Magento2?

Tags: magento2, layout, catalogsearch, seo, index

As the title states: How can I **add meta noindex to all catalog search result pages in Magento2**?

I am hoping for an **XML Layout** solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To me you can simply create the following files **in your module**:

- `view/frontend/layout/catalogsearch_advanced_result.xml`
- `view/frontend/layout/catalogsearch_result_index.xml`

**In case of a theme**, the file locations will be different, under your theme folder:

- `Magento_CatalogSearch/layout/catalogsearch_advanced_result.xml`
- `Magento_CatalogSearch/layout/catalogsearch_result_index.xml`

And add the following content to those files (same content for both):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <meta name="robots" content="NOINDEX,NOFOLLOW"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

Comment: Hi, this works nice for catalogsearch, what about to add noindex to /customer urls?

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/302721/how-to-make-noindex-nofollow-for-login-page