# how to make noindex nofollow for login page

Tags: layout, xml, login, seo, no-index

I want to make noindex nofollow for login page, i tried

```
 <customer_account_login translate="label">
        <label>Customer Account Login Form</label>
        <!-- Mage_Customer -->
        <remove name="right"/>
        <remove name="left"/>
      <!--   <remove name="header"/>
        <remove name="footer"/> -->

        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="customer/form_login" name="customer_form_login" template="customer/form/login.phtml" />
        </reference>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="setRobots"><value>NOINDEX,NOFOLLOW</value></action>
        </reference>
    </customer_account_login>
```

But it is not working, can any one suggest how to make no index no follow for login page

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a layout XML file:

Inside the "layout" directory, create a file named "customer_account_login.xml".
Add the following code to the "customer_account_login.xml" file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow" />
    </head>
</page>
```

2. Run Below Command and check
   **php bin/magento setup:upgrade**
   **php bin/magento cache:clean**

Answer (score 0):

Override `customer_account_login.xml` File in your module or you can also override using custom theme

```
<head>
 <meta name="robots" content="NOINDEX,NOFOLLOW"/>
</head>
```